# How to display a tree with a root at the bottom but leaves in left-to-right order?

Tags: trees

With the `Tree` function, I can draw arbitrary trees:

```
Tree[f, {1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

However, real trees grow from the ground to the sky. When I pass the `TreeLayout -> Bottom` option, the leaves become in the wrong order:

[image]

How can I make leaves appear in the correct order, in the graphical display of `Tree` with a root at the bottom? Is there a built-in way to do that, or should I write my own function that reverses leaves on the fly?

Comment: `Tree[f, Reverse@{1, 2, 3}, TreeLayout -> Bottom]`

Answer (score 5):

```
children[ent : Entity["Person", _]] := 
  Replace[ent[EntityProperty["Person", "Children"]], 
   _Missing -> {}]; 
children[_] = {}; 

NestTree[children, Entity["Person", 
  "QueenElizabethII::f5243"], 2, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

```
NestTree[Reverse@*children, Entity["Person", 
  "QueenElizabethII::f5243"], 2, ImageSize -> 1000,
 TreeLayout -> Bottom]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the example given in the comment below

```
bottomsUp[
  tree_Tree] := (tree //. 
    Tree[lbl_, br_List] :> temp[lbl, Reverse@br]) //. 
  temp :> (Tree[##, TreeLayout -> Bottom] &)
```

**EDIT 2:** or a little cleaner

```
bottomsUp[tree_Tree] := (tree //. Tree[lbl_, br_List] :>
     temp[lbl, Reverse@br, TreeLayout -> Bottom]) //. 
  temp :> Tree

origtree = Tree[Subscript[μ, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}], 
     {Tree[Subscript[μ, {1, 2}, {3, 4}], 
         {Tree[Subscript[ι, {1}]^{1, 2}, 
      {Subscript[ι, {}]^{1}}], Subscript[ι, {3}]^{3, 4}}], 
   Tree[Subscript[μ, {5}, {6}], {Subscript[ι, {}]^{6}, id}]}]
```

[image]

```
bottomsUp[origtree]
```

[image]

Comment: I have multi-level trees that are not generated by NestTree. Your answer is very specific to that function.

Comment: Then post an example that demonstrates the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Since there does not appear to be a built-in way to achieve what I want, here is  my code (which is maybe a bit simpler than the other answer, although probably less efficient due to recursion):

```
bottom[t_?TreeLeafQ] := t

bottom[Tree[root_, children_]] := 
 Tree[root, bottom /@ Reverse[children], TreeLayout -> Bottom]
```

---

Well, seems like my hunch was wrong. My code is about 5x faster:

```
tree = RandomTree[2000]

RepeatedTiming[bottomsUp[tree];]
(* {0.0446962, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[bottom[tree];]
(* {0.0088462, Null} *)
```